# Controller method does not exist. But actually exists. Not passing value with request neither

Tags: model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, http-post, php-7, laravel-5.7

This is just driving me crazy. A lot of research, testing, double checking the rotes with artisan, and even a new clean laravel installation to make sure my routes are working fine, and i keep getting the error that my method does not exist and it does not matter if i change namespace, or the method name.

**My route web.php**

```
Route::get('/view1', function () {
    return view('view1');
});

Route::post('/view1results', [
    "uses" => 'MyController@MyMethod',
    "as" => 'MySearch'
]);

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

**My view1:**

```
  <label class="myfilters">filters:</label>
    <form action="{{ route('MySearch') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <select class="myfilters" id="filter1" name="filter1">
    <option value=""> -- Select Something --</option>
        <option value="">  option 1 </option>
        <option value="">  option 2 </option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

**My Controller**

```
<?php
use Input;
use app\SubSectorsBPIsData;
use App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

    class SubSectorsBPIsDataController extends Controller
    {
        public function MyMethod(Request $request)
        {
            $valueselected= $request->input('filter1');
             return view('view1results', ['filter1' => $valueselected]);
        }
     }
```

**Error** is: *BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Controllers\MyController::MyMethod does not exist.* 
And as you can see the method called: *MyMethod* is there. 
It does not matter what i put on my view1results, i was just trying a simple `{{echo $valueselected}};`

Also tried to add another different view to pass data from my controller. In my web.php:

```
Route::get('/viewresults2', function () {
    return view('viewresults2');
});
```

And then in my controller

```
return view('viewresults2', ['filter1' => $valueselected]);
```

It gives me a blank page. 
Even if with this other approach it's recognizing the method, it's now returning any view nor value: If i just bypass the view and try to: 
`return   $selectedTrend;` 
Still get a blank page.

It's not recognizing the method and it's not passing any value from the select.
Whats going on please? :(

**Update**
One more thing: my website is file structure is:

> www.mydomain.net/software/public/view1

And after submiting the form redirects to:

> www.mydomain.net/software/public/view1results

Just adding it up so you could help me better with the route, since i think that's where the problem is and i couldn't figure out what route to use on my action form.

Comment: ok. Actually when bypassing the view and doing only ´return hola;´ it's showing the *hola* But still lost on why is not passing the value and giving me that error. 
It's like if it's ignoring everything i put in the controller, and just redirecting after submit.

Comment: When you `dd($valueselected)`, what does it say?

Comment: I did it on my controller inside MyMethod and still is telling me that my MyMethod doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a silly mistake (like always). In my view i had this code for the dropdown:

```
<select class="myfilters" id="filter1" name="filter1">
    <option value=""> -- Select Something --</option>
        <option value="">  option 1 </option>
        <option value="">  option 2 </option>
    </select>
```

Notice the `<option value="">` does not have any value and controller needs to know which value to get. So do this instead:

```
<option value="option1">  option1 </option>
<option value="option2">  opion2 </option>
```

And controller will get the value. All the rest it's set properly. 
Hope it helps another newbie in

### Laravel 5.7